# C# Selenium WebDriver - FirefoxDriver error: Failed to start up socket within 45000

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the below exception when I try to run the selenium c# webdriver scripts using Firefox browser.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Failed to start up socket within 45000
  Source=WebDriver
  StackTrace:
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.ConnectToBrowser(Int64 timeToWaitInMilliSeconds) in
```

The same scripts were working fine two days back and not sure why it is failing now.

- I have added the selenium DLL directly to my PROJECT and no NUGETS [Dont know what are they]
- I tried viewing netstat and could nt see any port running for 45000
  cmd> netstat -abno | find /n /i "45000"
- I tried deleting the entire automation framework suite and checked out the code from SVN. DIDNT WORK
- I delete the firefox profile, uninstalled and installed new firefox profile. Didnot help.

It's quite suprising as what causes this error all of a sudden and for months I am running these scripts and working fine. The same "Solution" works in different PC as well with firefox and runs in chrome browser in my machine.

P.S - I am using selenium 2.23 and dont think I need to upgrade the version as the same scripts working perfectly in a different machine.

Could you let me know any alternatives I can try to fix this please.

Comment: Then the issue is software related. Firewall? Antivirus? Windows Updates? Has Firefox updated recently? Both computers have the **exact same** version of Firefox?

Comment: Hi Arran, Thanks for the response. There is no firewall restriction. But the firefox got updated recently and due to this error , I uninstalled and reinstalled firefox as well. Can Windows update be a problem?? Also Antivirus was the from the begining.. Do I need to suspect it as well??

Comment: Have you tried downgrading Firefox?

Comment: Will try and let you know. thanks again :)

Comment: It worked. I am using selenium 2.23 version and when I installed Firefox 15 version it worked. The upgrade of firefox to 16 or 17 didnot work. Reckon this is the right time, I need to update my selenium version :) Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it with updating my `Selenium` packages with `NuGet`.

I would recommend you add `NuGet` to `Visual Studio` and add the `Selenium` packages that way, and it will probably solve the problem for you.

I also had the similar problems with `Chrome` and `IE` drivers for `Selenium`, which are not available through `NuGet` and I solved the problems here by downloading the latest versions from the [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) site.

Comment: Thanks for your time to respond.. I wish I could, But everyone in my organization are using the same one and it works fine for them. Whatever changes I make , I should commit the code which I am not sure is acceptable as the error occurs only in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the matching version of Firefox with selenium IDE.

You probably need to downgrade Firefox ot upgrade selenium IDE such as Arran comment's.

I had the same problem because I had selenium 1.9 and Firefox 17 but this version of the ide has to be release :

[Selenium release notes](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes)

1.10.0 (to be released)
New - Added support for Firefox 16 & 17

1.9.1
New - Added support for Firefox 15

1.9.0
New - Added support for Firefox 14

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved if all selenium components (RC, Support, WebDriver, WebDriverBackedSelenium) are uninstalled through NuGet and installed again through NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solve it by updating my Selenium version to 2.31 and then reinstall firefox, because it was localted in Program Files (x86)/Firefox **3.6**/ (I always upgraded it before and its location didn't change since 3.6 version). After reinstalling and rebooting all works OK.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by

- copying the testing project up several directly levels
- into a new solution
- not under a directory junction any longer.

I knew something was off when the same code and same project that worked in one folder, didn't work in another.

Answer (score 0):

Remove webdriver dlls currently added in your project and install fresh dlls from Nuget. I got the the same error, i had added Firebug to firefox or may be it got updated so older versions of dlls were not supporting.